# FileNotFoundException :<nativehr>0x80070002</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>

Tags: development, debugging

Error related to `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`.

Trying to get **Survey 1**, **Survey 2** from Custom list Survey with 2 Columns:

1. Title
2. Url - Contains URL of Survey 1 or Survey 2

Custom Survey list Contain Following Survey

1. Survey 1 - Survey [out of box]
2. Survey 2 - Survey [out of box]

Reference Code:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate() { 
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPList list = web.Lists["Survey list"];

        foreach (SPListItem item in itemCollections)
        {
            string Url = item["URL"].ToString();
            string[] url=Url.Split(',');
            var listUrl = url[0];  //http://pc6/Surveys/Lists/Survey 1
            string relativeUrl = new Uri(listUrl).AbsolutePath; // /Surveys/Lists/Survey%201
            var ServerRelativeurl="/"+relativeUrl.Split('/')[1];
            var surveyListUrl=relativeUrl.Split('/')[2];
            var surveyUrl = relativeUrl.Split('/')[3];

            SPWeb surveyWeb = site.OpenWeb(ServerRelativeurl);
            var relativeUrlForList = "/" + surveyListUrl + "/" + surveyUrl;
            // Error
            SPList List = surveyWeb.GetList(relativeUrlForList);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: have you printed out all the string manipulation you're doing? Are you sure the list URL is correct? Try printing it out and accessing it with powershell to make it easier to test. Also, your surveyWeb isn't being disposed.

Comment: Yes m,sure list URL is correct.

Comment: What is "itemCollections"? Is it your "list.GetItems()"? Put a using around your surveyWeb-object for disposing the object. Besides that your code seems to be working, if the URL field is set properly (although it could still be cleaned up a bit and your variable naming like "Url" and "url" should not only differ by upper/lower case, chose something self-explanatory that's not so irritating).

Comment: SPListItemCollection itemCollections = list.GetItems(query);

Answer (score 1):

The way you split and join URLs is a little messy at best, so I'm not sure I understand it correctly.

It seems that you try to open a list using `/Lists/Survey 1` URL. This is web-relative URL. According to [SPWeb.GetList()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.getlist.aspx) you should use server-relative URL (like `/Surveys/Lists/Survey 1`).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use this code:

```
string strUrl = "http://url";
SPSite siteCollection = newSPSite(strUrl);
SPWeb web  = siteCollection.OpenWeb();
```